# adding user input into hash

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to ask three different users, three questions. I want to add their responses to an array which will be the value pair of a hash. I'm looking for something like this.

```
myhash={ "person1"=>[1, 2, 3], "person2"=>[4, 5, 5], "person3"=>[2, 6, 
9]}
```

ps. the numbers are inputs from the users.

can someone help me, im new to this:/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to know what you tried. That way we can directly address any problems in your code. As written it looks like you haven't tried anything and want us to write it for you, which is not the way that Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3 # number of persons
questions = ["who?: ", "what?: ", "where?: "]
```

If "person 1" answers "1", "2", "3" to "who?: ", "what?: ", "where?: ", "person2" answers "4", "5", "5" to the same questions and "person3" answers "2", "6", "9",
then:

```
(1..n).each_with_object({}) do |person,h|
  puts "Person #{person}, please answer the following questions"
  h["person#{person}"] = questions.map { |q| print q; gets.to_i }
end
  #=> {"person1"=>[1, 2, 3], "person2"=>[4, 5, 5], "person3"=>[2, 6, 9]}
```